# Joomla custom field type when editing

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, custom-field-type

how do make it so that when I edit an entry, the correct value for my custom field type is selected? I have this so far:

```
class JFormFieldCustom extends JFormField {

    protected $type = 'Custom';

    // getLabel() left out

    public function getInput() {

            return '<select id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'">'.
                        '<option value="1" >1</option>'.
                        '<option value="2" >2</option>'.
                    '</select>';
    }
```

}

How do I pass the selected value to this class so I can do:

```
<option value="1"SELECTED>1</option>
```

or

```
<option value="2" SELECTED>2</option>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you using this field (e.g. in your components item paramaters, in a menu.. etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$this->value` to get selected value.Try this-

```
 class JFormFieldCustom extends JFormField {

        protected $type = 'Custom';

        // getLabel() left out

        public function getInput() {

                return '<select id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'">'.
                            '<option value="1" <?php echo ($this->value==1)?'selected':''?>>1</option>'.
                            '<option value="2" <?php echo ($this->value==2)?'selected':''?>>2</option>'.
                        '</select>';
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to use what's already there, i.e. extend `JFormFieldList` in place of `JFormField`, then all you have to do is return the `option's` for your list. The inherited functionality will do the rest for you - including selecting the option that matches `$this->value`

```php
<?php
/**
 * Do the Joomla! security check and get the FormHelper to load the class
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');

JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldMyCustomField extends JFormFieldList
{
    /**
     * Element name
     *
     * @var     string
     */
    public  $type = 'MyCustomField';

    /**
     * getOptions() provides the options for the select
     *
     * @return  array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        // Create an array for our options
        $options = array();
        // Add our options to the array
        $options[] = array("value" => 1, "text" => "1);
        $options[] = array("value" => 1, "text" => "1);
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select for Joomla
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
 * @copyright (c) 2017 YouTech Company. All Rights Reserved.
 * @author macasin
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldSelect extends JFormFieldList
{
    protected $type = 'select';

```
protected function getInput()
{
    $html = array();
    $attr = '';

    // Initialize some field attributes.
    $attr .= !empty($this->class) ? ' class=select ' . $this->class . '"' : ' class=select ';
    $attr .= $this->readonly ? ' readonly' : '';
    $attr .= $this->disabled ? ' disabled' : '';
    $attr .= !empty($this->size) ? ' size="' . $this->size . '"' : '';
    $attr .= $this->required ? ' required aria-required="true"' : '';

    // Initialize JavaScript field attributes.
    $attr .= $this->onchange ? ' onchange="' . $this->onchange . '"' : '';

    // Get the field options.
    $options = $this->getOptions();

    // Load the combobox behavior.
    JHtml::_('behavior.combobox');

    $html[] = '<div class="select input-append">';

    // Build the input for the combo box.
    $html[] = '<select name="' . $this->name . '" id="' . $this->id . '" value="'
        . htmlspecialchars($this->value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"' . $attr . ' autocomplete="off" >';

    foreach ($options as $option)
    {
        $html[] = '<option '.($option->value == $this->value ? "selected" : "").' value='.$option->value.'>' . $option->text . '</option>';

    }
    $html[] = '</select></div>';

    return implode($html);
}
```

}